# Jenkinsのシェルからnode ●●.js を実行するとcommand not found になる

Tags: node.js, macos, command-line, shellscript

ホームフォルダにNodeJsというフォルダがあり、
Jenkins上のシェルからその中にNodejsをインストールする事はできました。

そしてNodeJsフォルダの中にLocalServer.jsというjsファイルがあり、
Jenkins上のシェルから

```
node LocalServer.js
```

とコマンドを実行したところ

```
node: command not found
```

というエラーが表示されました。

vncでJenkinsの起動しているサーバーに接続して、
ターミナルから同様の事を行うと成功します。

原因を探りたいのですが、全く同じフォルダで全く同じ動作をしているので
何から調べていいかわからずヒントでも良いのでご意見をいただけないでしょうか？

MacOSX：10.10.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins の場合に、node のある場所に PATH が通っていないのでしょう。
node を full path で書くと Jenkins からでも動きませんか?

Comment: cdを使用せずフルパスで実行してみたのですが、同じくcommand not found になりました。　NodeJsフォルダの中にインストールされているはずなのですが、bash_profile か .bashrc などでパスを通す必要があるんでしょうか？

Comment: Jenkins のシェルから ls -l /full/path/to/node を確認してみてください。見えてますか?

Comment: エラーとなりました、ls: /full/path/to/node: No such file or directory　サーバー自身でも同じコマンドを打ってもエラーとなりました。　　また、Jenkinsからnode -v　と打ってエラーとなり、サーバー自身で打つとバージョンが返ってきました。

Comment: 少し気になったのですが、/full/path/to/node の部分は実際の node の full path に置き換えてますか?

Comment: 書き換えてみました、それでもダメだったので echo $PATH でリモートログイン時とJenkinsとで比べたところ　/user/local/bin　のパスが通ってない事がわかったのでJenkins でシェルにexport= /usr/local/bin をしてパスが通るようにしました。　これでnodeの実行が可能となりました。